Special case for &lt and &gt
what would I do if i just randomly wanted to write &lt or &gt in HTML but I don't want to make it appear as a < or >. I understand I can use Javascript but I'm just wondering if there's a way in HTML.
Maybe there is a spacer that separates letters but does not appear in the screen?

Duplicate How to write out HTML entity name ( , <, >, etc)

You can write & as &amp;, so to answer your question: &amp;lt; and &amp;gt;.

Not sure why the downvote but this answer is correctly answering the question.

@Webber probably because there are questions like this already.
